# Exibir imagens .tiff no html

Tags: html, html5, imagem

Eu preciso exibir em um modal uma imagem, o problema é que ela é .tiff

Já pesquisei em vários lugares, e não consegui encontrar uma solução. Alguém consegue ajudar?

Comment: ja tentou abri-la no paint e salvar como png?

Comment: Na verdade quem deve suportar o formato é o navegador Web, você pode convertê-la antes de publicar ou, caso ela seja gerada dinamicamente, usar uma biblioteca como o [tiff.js][https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js] para a tarefa.

Comment: Os usuários do sistema fazem o upload de imagens .tiff no sistema. Eu só preciso dar um jeito de exibir a imagem que eles uparam quando é feita a consulta.

Vou tentar usar essa biblioteca js